# Exclude pages from PHP query

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have this chunk of PHP that excluded a certain element from appearing on all of my WordPress pages, while keeping them on posts/products, but there's a couple of pages where I would still like it to appear.

How do I go about excluding certain Page IDs from this query?

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'avada_check_page' );
function avada_check_page() {
if ( is_singular( 'page' ) ) {
add_action( 'avada_override_current_page_title_bar', 'avada_remove_title_bar' );
}
}
function avada_remove_title_bar() {
}
```

There's about 100 pages I want to apply this to and only 5 where I want to exclude them from this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would just be to use a condition on that first if statement.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'avada_check_page' );
function avada_check_page() {
    if ( is_singular( 'page' ) && !in_array(get_the_ID(),array(1,2,3,4)) ) {
        add_action( 'avada_override_current_page_title_bar', 'avada_remove_title_bar' );
    }
}
function avada_remove_title_bar() {

}
```

Where `1,2,3,4` place the exceptions posts ID's.

Comment: Thanks, worked brilliantly once I swapped out the Page IDs